# Why i get internal server error 500 about php files?

Tags: php, html, server, centos, cwp

I am using cwp(centos web panel) for my vitural server and I am using apache when I load php files in htdocs I get error 500 internal server error. 
But it is not true about html files.
I change php files permission to full access but there is no change.
Im using centos7 and phpmyadmin. 
It's not about php codes I get this error even for empty php files but only php files.

Comment: This means, that the php script died because of an error. Check the logs.

Comment: Maybe your php interpreter is not installed or configured properly. As Markus said the logs (should be in ´/var/log/apache/´) should tell you the problem.